# How much street space can restaurants occupy?

Tags: france, restaurants

In Paris, France, what define how much street space can a restaurant occupy?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the document [Reglement des etalages et terrasses](http://www.tout-paris.org/nouvelles-regles-terrasses-cafe-12922), page 15, such installations may not exceed 50% of the usable area of the sidewalk, and must leave a contiguous area of at least 1.6 meters in width for pedestrian traffic:

> Les installations peuvent être autorisées, soit d’un seul tenant, soit scindées, sans pouvoir excéder 50% de la largeur utile du trottoir.  Une zone contiguë d’au moins 1,60 mètre de largeur doit être réservée à la circulation des piétons.

If you are interested in looking directly at the laws concerned, these can be found at the beginning of the same document:

> Les dispositions du présent règlement sont établies en application
>   des articles L.2122-1 à L.2122-3 du code général de la Propriété des personnes publiques, L.2512-13, L.2512-14 et L.2213-6 du code général des Collectivités territoriales et de l’article L.113-2 du code de la Voirie routière.

Roughly translated, that means that the rules described in the present document are established by application of the articles L.2122-1 through L.2122-3 of the "general code of property of public persons", L.2512-13, L.2512-14 and L.2213-6 of the "general code of territorial collectivities" and of article L.113-2 of the highway code.

More links:

[L.2122-1](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070299&idArticle=LEGIARTI000006361200)

[L.2122-2](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006361201&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070299)

[L.2122-3](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006361202&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070299)

[L.2512-13](http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070633&idArticle=LEGIARTI000020629800)

[L.2512-14](http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000028538329&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070633)

[L.2213-6](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006390184&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070633)

[L.113-2](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070667&idArticle=LEGIARTI000017924078)